# datagridview show dropdown when cell is empty in edit mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with datagridview with 4 columns. I add all the values using "Add". No datatable or datasourse. The 3 columns is a ComboBoxColumn and the value can be edited. When i write in the cell the dropdown hide correctly. And then I want that when I delete all the strings in the cell (when the cell is empty) the dropdown appears.

But in EditMode when i change the cell original value (Ej: AAA) for (Ej: BBB), the code used to get the value always show the original value.

Another thing, I don't know if the code to show the dropdown menu is correct because of the problem that I already explained.
Edit: I check and that part work correctly. DroppedDown = true show the dropdown.

```
private void DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxHandler = e.Control as ComboBox;

            if (comboBoxHandler != null)
            {
                comboBoxHandler.IntegralHeight = false;   //Sin esto el MaxDropDownItems no funciona
                comboBoxHandler.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
                comboBoxHandler.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                comboBoxHandler.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
                comboBoxHandler.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;

                comboBoxHandler.KeyPress -= ComboBox_KeyPress;
                comboBoxHandler.KeyPress += ComboBox_KeyPress;

                comboBoxHandler.LostFocus += Combo_LostFocus;
            }
        }
```

```
void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)   //ComboBox_KeyDown
        {
            if (dgvCustom.IsCurrentCellInEditMode && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)dgvCustom.CurrentCell.Value))
            {
                comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown = true;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown = false;
            }
        }
```

Edit: For anyone seeing this code, don't put this (comboBoxHandler.KeyPress -= ComboBox_KeyPress;, comboBoxHandler.LostFocus -= Combo_LostFocus;) in "EditingControlShowing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the comboBox TextChanged Event to make the dropdown appears when the comboBox is empty and hide when not. But I used the ComboBox_KeyPress to make the dropdown hide because wanted a different behavior.

```
    private void DataGridView_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)dgvCustom.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue))
        {
            comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```

Ex 2:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxHandler.Text) && comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown == false)
        {
            comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown = true;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxHandler.Text) && comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown == true)
        {
            comboBoxHandler.DroppedDown = false;
        }
```